Video cannot open more options in edge
<el-dialog v-model="videoDialog">
    <video v-if="videoDialog" :src="videoSrc" style="width:100%;height:500px;" controls="controls" crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
  </el-dialog>

enter image description here
It's this button that doesn't respond when clicked
enter image description here
Add "top: 0px!" to this tag! important;left: 0px !important; It will be displayed, but the display position is incorrect
video::-internal-media-controls-overflow-menu-list {
  top: 0px !important;
  bottom: 0px !important;
}

but no effect

I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. It seems that you're using framework element-plus. Could you please provide a minimal code snippet which can reproduce the issue? Besides, have you tried in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox to see if it has the same issue?

https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/issues/16978

Now that it has been updated to the latest version (125.0.6422.113), Google Chrome will also encounter this issue

It seems that adding ". el overview log {position: absolute! Important;}" can solve the problem

Yes, I test in Edge 125.0.2535.67 and Chrome 125.0.6422.113, the results are the same. I think it's an element-plus compatibility issue with chromium. Glad that you have found a workaround! You can also post it as an answer so that it can help others in future with similar issue.

.el-overlay-dialog {
    position: absolute !important;
}

